# How to enable / disable programmatically automatic text scrolling in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I need to enable automatic horizontal scrolling of text for a TextView but also be able to disable it.
Enabling it works fine with the following code

```
            textView.setFocusable(true);
            textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
            textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
            textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            textView.setSingleLine();
            textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            textView.setSelected(true);
```

But calling the following code to disable the animation fails

```
            textView.setFocusable(false);
            textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            textView.setSingleLine(false);
            textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            textView.setSelected(false);
```

How can I disable the scrolling animation programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean; You clicked your textView, textView's scrolling will gone? I tried your codes and ıt works in my project but I can not understand , what exactly you want. Can you explain your  mean that; "How can I disable the scrolling animation by code?"

Comment: No I mean that I want to control the automatic scrolling manually by code.

Comment: Could you please add this peace of code android:scrollbars = "horizontal" to layout's textview. And add your activity to textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); Lastly . ; erase your code in second part in your activity.The result is as you wish ?

Comment: I'm sorry but what you're proposing doesn't make any sense. All I want is to enable/disable automatic text scrolling. The first code do this properly but I'm unabled to disable it after that. I'm sorry but it looks like you didn't understand the question/issue

Comment: Could you please describe where you're calling the start and stop animation functions?

Comment: Because I tested your code and it looks fine.
MainActivity:
https://gist.github.com/PedroOkawa/0d8510725b2f22412cd8fd355f9eb0ed

activity_main:
https://gist.github.com/PedroOkawa/398ec0710ee4390fee96ebf7ce19b24f

Comment: Have you tried calling, textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(false).